# can not Insert more than one records in sqlite database

Tags: android

I insert data into sqlite database table and when i insert first record , it is inserted successfully , but the second and all next records are not inserted. here is my database helper class.
i have tried the same queries in sqlite manager in firefox and they work fine. I can not get any idea why they are not working in my code.

```
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE + "( " + KEY_ROWID +
        " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_DESCRIPTION + " text, "+ KEY_WHY+" text , "+ KEY_ACCOUNTABILITY+
        " text , "+KEY_ALARM_TYPE+" text , "+KEY_ALARM_VOLUME+" text,  "+KEY_BG_IMAGE+" text, "+KEY_CATEGORY+"  text, "+KEY_DATE_TIME+  " datetime "+" , "+KEY_STATUS+" text );";
    public void addRecord(String description,String why, String accontability, String alarm_type,
            String alarm_vol, String bg_image, String category, Date goalDateTime,String status) {
        String query = "INSERT INTO " + DATABASE_TABLE + " VALUES(null,'"+ description + "', '" + why +  "', '" + accontability +"','" + alarm_type +
                "', '" + alarm_vol +  "', '" + bg_image +"','" +category+ "','" +  goalDateTime +"','"+status+"');";
        Log.v("--->", query);
        try{
        mDB.execSQL(query);



    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.v("database error", ex.toString());

    }
    }
```

here i am adding data in table

```
    try {
        /*
         * dbHelper = new GoalDbAdapter(this); dbHelper.open();
         * Log.v("database ","database opened"); // dbHelper. fillData();
         */
        db = new GoalDbAdapter(this);
        db.open();
        String imagePath = pref.getValue("imagePath", "");
        String goalCateg = pref.getValue("categText", "");
        String vol = pref.getValue("vol", "");
        String alarmType=  pref.getValue("ringTonePath", "");
        db.addRecord(goal_desc, goal_why, accountability, alarmType, vol, imagePath, goalCateg, goalDate,"");
         cursor = db.getTop3Goals();
        Log.v("cursor count in add act",".."+cursor.getCount());
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.v("database error", ex.toString());

    }
```

Here is my code to get goals , i am unable to fetch all data , it returns only the first goal and not others. All these methods are returning only the first goal.

```
     public Cursor getGoals() {
    Cursor c_all = mDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE, null);
    int count= c_all.getCount();
    Log.v("cursor count in db all goals", c_all.getCount()+"..");
    c_all.moveToFirst();
    return c_all;
}

//SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 5

public Cursor getTop3Goals() {
    Cursor c = mDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ORDER BY "+ KEY_DATE_TIME + " DESC LIMIT 3", null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    return c;
}

public Cursor getGoalsByDate() {
    Cursor c = mDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ORDER BY "+ KEY_DATE_TIME + " DESC ", null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    return c;
}
```

Comment: the fact that the first insert is successful points to some issue with your row  ids , you might be sending the same row id for insert hence first time it works but later it doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your insert method like this:

```
    public void addRecord(String description,String why, String accontability, String alarm_type,
                    String alarm_vol, String bg_image, String category, Date goalDateTime,String status){

      ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();

      initialValues.put(KEY_DESCRIPTION , description);
      initialValues.put(KEY_WHY, why);
      initialValues.put(KEY_ACCOUNTABILITY, accontability);
      initialValues.put(KEY_ALARM_TYPE, alarm_type);

      initialValues.put(KEY_ALARM_VOLUME, alarm_vol);
      initialValues.put(KEY_BG_IMAGE, bg_image);
      initialValues.put(KEY_CATEGORY, category);
      initialValues.put(KEY_DATE_TIME, goalDateTime);
      initialValues.put(KEY_STATUS, status);

      long rowId = mDB.insert(DATABASE_TABLE , null, initialValues);


}
```

`rowId` is the row id number of the new record.

**EDIT:**  Try the next code:

```
public Cursor getGoals() {
    Cursor cursor = mDB.query(DATABASE_TABLE, null, null, null, null, null, null);

        if ((cursor != null) && (cursor.getCount() > 0)) {
            cursor.moveToNext();

            return cursor;
        }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks OfirAN, I have tried this but the problem is still there. :(

Comment: Hmmm the rowid returned shows that data is inserted into database but there is some problem with fetching data, let me check it , otherwise i will upload the code for that as well . many thanks

Comment: Here is my code to get goals , i am unable to fetch all data , it returns only the first goal and not others. All these methods are returning only the first goal.


public Cursor getGoals() {
  Cursor c = mDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE, null);
  
  Log.v("cursor count in db all goals", c.getCount()+"..");
  c.moveToFirst();
  return c;
 }

 //SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 5
 
 public Cursor getTop3Goals() {
  Cursor c = mDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ORDER BY "+ KEY_DATE_TIME + " DESC LIMIT 3", null);
  c.moveToFirst();
  return c;
 }

Comment: @user1399214 Did you try to recreate your table? maybe you need to recreate it to fix the row id problem. Just delete your DB file and then the table would automatically recreated.